# Why does FindLibrary return 0?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create a launcher for SAMP Android. Everything was going well until the integration of SAMP itself ([build69](https://github.com/Hobr/SA-MP-Android/tree/master)). libsamp.so cannot find the address of the neighboring libGTASA.so library.

Initializing all libraries (Java)

```
static {
        vmVersion = null;
        System.out.println("**** Loading SO's");
        try
        {
            vmVersion = System.getProperty("java.vm.version");
            System.out.println("vmVersion " + vmVersion);
            System.out.println("**** Loading libImmEmulatorJ.so");
            System.loadLibrary("ImmEmulatorJ");
        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError | UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        }
        System.out.println("**** Loading libGTASA.so");
        System.loadLibrary("GTASA");
        System.out.println("**** Loading libsamp.so");
        System.loadLibrary("samp");
    }
```

Finding a library in libsamp.so (C++ JNI)

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
  Log("SAMP library loaded! Build time: " __DATE__ " " __TIME__);

  g_libGTASA = FindLibrary("libGTASA.so");
  if(g_libGTASA == 0)
  {
    Log("ERROR: libGTASA.so address not found!");
    return 0;
  }

  Log("libGTASA.so image base address: 0x%X", g_libGTASA);

  srand(time(0));

  InitHookStuff();
  InitRenderWareFunctions();
  InstallSpecialHooks();

  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, 0, Init, 0);

  struct sigaction act;
  act.sa_sigaction = handler;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0);

  return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

FindLibrary:

```
uintptr_t FindLibrary(const char* library)
{
    char filename[0xFF] = {0},
    buffer[2048] = {0};
    FILE *fp = 0;
    uintptr_t address = 0;

    sprintf( filename, "/proc/%d/maps", getpid() );

    fp = fopen( filename, "rt" );
    if(fp == 0)
    {
        Log("ERROR: can't open file %s", filename);
        goto done;
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
    {
        if( strstr( buffer, library ) )
        {
            address = (uintptr_t)strtoul( buffer, 0, 16 );
            break;
        }
    }

    done:

    if(fp)
      fclose(fp);

    return address;
}
```

Application log:

```
2023-10-28 14:57:32.800 29054-29054 System.out              com.kalinovka.game                   I  **** Loading SO's
2023-10-28 14:57:32.800 29054-29054 System.out              com.kalinovka.game                   I  vmVersion 2.1.0
2023-10-28 14:57:32.800 29054-29054 System.out              com.kalinovka.game                   I  **** Loading libImmEmulatorJ.so
2023-10-28 14:57:32.804 29054-29054 System.out              com.kalinovka.game                   I  **** Loading libGTASA.so
2023-10-28 14:57:32.813 29054-29054 NVEvent                 com.kalinovka.game                   D  JNI_OnLoad called
2023-10-28 14:57:32.813 29054-29054 NVEvent                 com.kalinovka.game                   D  RegisterNatives 12
2023-10-28 14:57:32.813 29054-29054 System.out              com.kalinovka.game                   I  **** Loading libsamp.so
2023-10-28 14:57:32.815 29054-29054 AXL                     com.kalinovka.game                   I  SAMP library loaded! Build time: Oct 28 2023 14:47:20
2023-10-28 14:57:32.819 29054-29054 AXL                     com.kalinovka.game                   I  ERROR: libGTASA.so address not found!
2023-10-28 14:57:32.820 29054-29054 AndroidRuntime          com.kalinovka.game                   D  Shutting down VM
2023-10-28 14:57:32.823 29054-29054 AndroidRuntime          com.kalinovka.game                   E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.kalinovka.game, PID: 29054
                                                                                                    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Bad JNI version returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/~~AIt22YvJlsdkRyH_N_WAEw==/com.kalinovka.game-G93aBwDihlPGnVBadiHFkQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libsamp.so": 0
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1082)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
                                                                                                        at com.kalinovka.game.core.GTASA.<clinit>(GTASA.java:28)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1287)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3701)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3977)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8249)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
2023-10-28 14:57:32.894 29054-29054 Process                 com.kalinovka.game                   I  Sending signal. PID: 29054 SIG: 9
```

Error: Invalid JNI version returned from JNI_OnLoad - since libsamp.so sent 0, you can ignore this

I removed all references to libsamp.so and the application works, GTASA itself is initialized by the id, this means that libGTASA.so is loaded and working.

I changed the library name in FindLibrary, it also returned zero. Indicates that there is a problem with access due to the Android API level.

I found the same problem on a Russian-language site, but there was no solution, but the question indicated that this error only occurs on Android API 30+

Comment: I displayed /proc/%d/maps and saw that there are a lot of different processes there, but I don’t need it, then where should I look for it?(

Comment: This bug makes me cry

Comment: The required JNI version is latter than your JVM’s.